# I have VMWare for Mac OS X, can I create VMs on Mac and use them on Windows 7 without buying another copy of VMWare?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualization, vmware-fusion

Basically I own a license of VMWare on my Mac. I want to create the VMs on the Mac and then run them on my Windows 7 laptop. Is this doable and legal? Or do I need to buy another copy of VMWare for Windows? Can the VMWare Player run them on Windows 7 and is that free?

Comment: Hi @Mousepad. While looking through some of your old questions, I noticed that you haven't accepted answers on most of them. It helps future visitors to know what solution worked, and you also will gain reputation points for accepting answers. Please consider going through some of your old questions and marking accepted answers where appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should be able to create a VM on your Mac and run it on Windows using VMWare Player.  See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290897/can-a-vmware-fusion-image-be-run-on-a-windows-machine).

[VMware Player is free for personal non-commercial use](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html).